# Adding FK to MySQL Table Not Working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, toad

I work with SQL Server and haven't had such an issue adding a FK to a table like I am having with MySQL.  The datatypes match up, the foreign key table contains 300K rows, and is taking forever to execute and eventually times out.  Am I doing something wrong?  I did this in Workbench and Toad, same thing happens.

The relationship is a one to one, with the User table primary key ID being used a a FK for the District Admins table primary key ID.

I dont know how to find the MySQL version, and can't tell you the amount of memory.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail like:  what version of mysql, what is the structure of the two tables and more importantly their indicies? how many records in the referencing table?

Comment: How much memory do you have allocated for MySql?

Comment: probably the structure you can share...would definitely be of some help here

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue was the table collations were different.  My new tables were using latin1, but the existing were using UTF8.  That is what I get for relying on Workbench to muchy.